# API con atributo con espacios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy utilizando una API que busca canciones, pero el atributo de la API "Song Name" tiene espacio y eso hace que me de como resultado "undefined", ¿saben como puedo obtenerlo?

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var songName = "Song Name";
    $.each(response.data, function(calzon, caca){
      console.log(caca.Artist, caca.Date, caca.songName);
    });
```

Pero en la consola me pone

> VIXX 2016-04-19 undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando no puedes acceder a un atributo, hay otra forma en la que puedes acceder a su valor, usando **[ ]**, aquí te va un ejemplo

```js
const caca = {
    Artist: "Dog",
  Date: "Cat",
  "Song Name": "CatDog"
}
console.log(caca.Artist, caca.Date, caca["Song Name"]);
```